# is it possible to instance as singleton a http client with HttpClientFactory for a gRPC client?

Tags: c#, .net, grpc, dotnet-httpclient

it seems it is not a good practice to create a HttpClient for each call to the server. This is commented here: https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Reading the documentation about HttpClientFactory, https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.Net.ClientFactory, it is said that the client is registered as transient, so it can be injected as dependency property.

Well, if the client is created as transient, it is creadted for each view model that need to use the service, so the advise that says that the life of the http client should to be for the whole life of the applications it is not followed. So I guess that I should to register the client as singlenton.

Is it possible to use the factory to register the client as singlton instead of transient?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this article applies to gRPC that much. The [client performace section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/client?view=aspnetcore-7.0#client-performance) in the MS gRPC documentation says: `gRPC clients are lightweight objects and don't need to be cached or reused`. The performance heavy task seems to be the re-creation of gRPC channels, which use the `HttpClientMessageHandler` type.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the article. But the problem it seems when a http client is created in windows, the problem is at windows level, so if I create a http client, no matter if it is for gRPC or another kind of client, then I guess the problem is the same. But sure it is possible my guess is incorrect.

Comment: Could also be that I am wrong :) The only way to find out for sure is doing some performance tests. As a solution the article you linked recommends to do the following thing at the end: `Make your HttpClient static`. When you set up the gRPC channel, you can maybe pass a client handler that points to a static http client object instead of the default handler that is used in the documentation examples, then you could figure out if it makes a performance difference? (in the `GrpcChannel.ForAddress(...)` method)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to do that. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/clientfactory?view=aspnetcore-7.0) the SDK:

> Manages the lifetime of the underlying `HttpClientMessageHandler`.

The service should properly manage the sockets.